# How to get user profile image from logged user with Twitter Kit/Fabric in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter

i'm using Fabric in order to add a "Sign In with Twitter" button in my app. Sign in process works fine, but I don't how (if it's possible) how to get the logged user's profile image.

Is there any property inside TWTRSession with this info (like userName and userID)? Looked for it but I didn't found anything?

```
[TWTRLogInButton buttonWithLogInCompletion:^(TWTRSession *session, NSError *error) {
  // I get user data here...
  // and need to get user Twitter's profile image
}];
```

Thanks

**EDIT**

Thanks to sak's answer, i figured out how to do it.

```
[TWTRLogInButton buttonWithLogInCompletion:^(TWTRSession *session, NSError *error) {
  [[[Twitter sharedInstance] APIClient] loadUserWithID:session.userID completion:^(TWTRUser *user, NSError *error) {
       NSLog(@"User image %@", user.profileImageURL);
  }];
}];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think the TWTRSession object has the user's image, but you can use the session to request a TWTRUser object, and that will have what you need.

Comment: Thanks, you put me in the right way. I'll edit my question with the correct answer.

Answer (score 14):

For those who are getting this error :

```
Value of type 'Twitter' has no member 'APIClient'
```

This helped me,

```
let twitterClient = TWTRAPIClient(userID: userID)
twitterClient.loadUserWithID(userID) { (user:TWTRUser?, error:NSError?) in
    print(user?.profileImageURL)
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Try below code to get **profile image** -

**Swift 3**

```
let twitterClient = TWTRAPIClient(userID: session?.userID)
    twitterClient.loadUser(withID: (session?.userID)!, completion: { (user, error) in
       print(user!.profileImageURL)
})
```

Answer (score 7):

The way to do it in swift is as follows:

```
Twitter.sharedInstance().APIClient.loadUserWithID( session.userID ) 
{
    (user, error) -> Void in

    if( user != nil )
    {

println( user.profileImageURL )

    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: It says : Value of type `'Twitter'` has no member `'APIClient'`

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
TWTRLogInButton *logInButton = [TWTRLogInButton buttonWithLogInCompletion:^(TWTRSession *session, NSError *error) {
    // play with Twitter session
    if (session) {
        NSLog(@"Twitter signed in as -> name = %@ id = %@ ", [session userName],[session userID]);

        /* Get user info */
        [[[Twitter sharedInstance] APIClient] loadUserWithID:[session userID]
                                                  completion:^(TWTRUser *user,
                                                               NSError *error)
        {
            // handle the response or error
            if (![error isEqual:nil]) {
                NSLog(@"Twitter info   -> user = %@ ",user);
                NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:user.profileImageLargeURL];
                NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:urlString];
                NSData *pullTwitterPP = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url];

                UIImage *profImage = [UIImage imageWithData:pullTwitterPP];


            } else {
                NSLog(@"Twitter error getting profile : %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            }
        }];

    } else {
        NSLog(@"Twitter error signed in : %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}];
logInButton.center = self.view.center;
[self.view addSubview:logInButton];
```

Comment: Is there any way to user Bio with `Fabric` ?

Comment: Yes, you can get user bio except birth day and gender.

Comment: I am getting profile image and name from TWTRUser . But i could not find any property to bio. By Bio I mean description user adds in profile

Comment: Have a look at this [link](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/show)

Comment: Thanks, @NSPratik. I'll try them all.

Answer (score 3):

To get the picture large size, you can build a URL as follow:

```
 if let twitterId = session.userID{
        let twitterClient = TWTRAPIClient(userID: twitterId)
        twitterClient.loadUser(withID: twitterId) {(user, error) in
           if let userName = user?.screenName{
              let url = "https://twitter.com/\(userName)/profile_image?size=original")
           }
        }
 }
```

This approach uses the twitter user name, then it will be redirected to the real profile picture size.

Answer (score 2):

```
 [[[Twitter sharedInstance] APIClient] loadUserWithID:[session userID] completion:^(TWTRUser *user, NSError *error) {
      }];
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I get userId,userName,authToken,authTokenSecret and **profileImageURL**

```
[[Twitter sharedInstance] logInWithCompletion:^(TWTRSession *session, NSError *error) {
        if (session != nil) {
            SPTWUser *user = [[SPTWUser alloc] init];
            user.userID = session.userID;
            user.userName = session.userName;
            user.authToken = session.authToken;
            user.authTokenSecret = session.authTokenSecret;

            TWTRAPIClient *client = [[TWTRAPIClient alloc] initWithUserID:user.userID];
            [client loadUserWithID:user.userID completion:^(TWTRUser * _Nullable user, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                NSLog(@"%@",user.profileImageURL);
            }];
        }
    }];
```

Reference [TWTRAPIClient Class](https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/ios-reference/twtrapiclient), [TWTRUser Class](https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/ios-reference/twtruser),[TWTRSession Class](https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/ios-reference/twtrsession)